# Chrome Extension - Simple Content Script for running js on any page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How can I write a simple Chrome Extension content script that will execute JavaScript (for example `alert("hello");`) on every page load?

So when I navigate to a page or reload a page, the JavaScript should run.

This is my `manifest.json` file so far:

```
{
    "name": "Highlight some phrases",
    "description": "Hightlight some pre defined text from websql database after page loads",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs","<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],

    "background": {
        "page": "background.html" 
    },

    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: sorry about my post. the codes looks wonky.. this is my first post.

Comment: {
 "name": "Highlight some phrases",
 "description": "Hightlight some pre defined text from websql database after page loads",
 "version": "0.1",
 "permissions": [
  "tabs","<all_urls>"
  ],
 "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

 "content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": [
   "http://*/*",
   "https://*/*"
   ],
  "js": ["content.js"]
  }
 ],


 "background": {
  "page": "background.html" 
  },

 "manifest_version": 2
}

Comment: The [Custom JavaScript for websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija) Chrome extension might me helpful. It lets you inject your own custome scripts into specific pages you choose, including ones relying on jQuery.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If all you need is to alert `hello` on every page load or reload, below is a simple demo: 
`Manifest.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Highlight some phrases",
    "description": "Hightlight some pre defined text after page loads",
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": [
        "tabs","<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
            ],
        "js": ["content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"    // Pay attention to this line
        }
    ], 
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and `content.js`:

```js
// alert("hello");
document.body.style.background = 'yellow';
```

Yes, that's enough.
And of course, don't forget to add an icon named `icon.png` at the same directory with these two files, then test it in Google Chrome.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing.. Could you please help me if I want to change background-color to eg. yellow. How can i do this ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, but it will not always work perfect, because   sites will be affected by their own js codes as well. You should really have a look at the tutorials of Google [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html). Now I'm gonna sleep. (1:30 am here). :) @user2876479

Comment: Thank you yakiang, It's been years since i wanted to develop some useful chrome extensions. but it's only been 2-3 days i've started. and Im' starting to understand a bit now. So my question could be stupid.. I thought I might need to use some commands like "chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener". Since I have also a popup, will that simple styling code effect the popup html or the tab's html. Still needs to find out so much about extensions.  I will definately try these out now. and share my experiences here asap.

Comment: and please do not edit your code.. These will be very useful to somebody like me who are begineers..

Comment: The *content_scripts > matches* property also supports *<all_urls>* so you don't have to bother with the multiple patterns for http, https, etc. Just do: `"matches": ["<all_urls>"],` which will match things like `file:///` as well.

Comment: Can you please update the manifest to version 3.