# how do i remove all html in webpage that says april fools

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I hate april fools and want to remove all html aka blank the  page if april fools is in the html via chrome extension. I looked at a selective easer exenstion and didnt understand it.How do i do this?

Comment: You need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that checks document.body.textContent, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As wOxxOm has [suggested](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), you can create your own [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347499/chrome-extension-simple-content-script-for-running-js-on-any-page) and inside you can use some code similar to this:

```
if(document.body.textContent.search("april fools") > -1) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "";
}
```